# Jade plant stem moving in different angles

Tags: identification, trees, jade, stems

[image]Ive had this jade plant for a few years now and its been doing well and healthy but one of the stems was bending over but about a week ago the same stem bended upward overnight and after a few days now the end of the stem is bending forward all the stems and leaves feel thick and strong and the plant seems healthy is this a problem or is it normal? Also about a month ago i pruned one of the stems if that is causing problems for it

Comment: Indoor plants become leggy like this. You can prune it and root the cuttings. Then the original plast regrows more bushy.

Answer (score 2):

It is probably just bending toward the sun. To prove, just turn the pot around and see if switches direction.